# check for empty, non-empty resultset by select query in mysql-python

Tags: mysql, database, python-3.x

Below is my python code to fetch a record from mysql DB table -

```
from mysql.connector import pooling, connect as mysql_connect
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = 'SELECT * from xyz WHERE name="{}"'
cursor.execute(query.format(name))
if cursor.with_rows:
    row = dict(zip(cursor.column_names, cursor.fetchone()))
```

In this code cursor.with_rows always returns True whether SELECT query returns a result or not.
I tried using cursor.rowcount but that always returns -1 even if I have a resutset returned from select statement.
Can anybody suggest what is wrong with the code or what checking condition should I use here?
I am usign Python 3.5 and MySql 5.x